# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpush'

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, web-push

I am using webpush in my Django application. Following the recommendation it works well locally.

When I push the code to my host, it gives me this mistake ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpush'.
Application does not work.

Error log:

---

2023-02-15 07:51:15,780: Error running WSGI application
2023-02-15 07:51:15,780: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpush'
2023-02-15 07:51:15,780:   File "/var/www/www_……….._pl_wsgi.py", line 30, in 
2023-02-15 07:51:15,781:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2023-02-15 07:51:15,781:
2023-02-15 07:51:15,781:   File "/home/……/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2023-02-15 07:51:15,781:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2023-02-15 07:51:15,781:
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:   File "/home/……/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:   File "/home/……./.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:   File "/home/…../.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
2023-02-15 07:51:15,782:     import_module(entry)
2023-02-15 07:51:15,783:

I did  « pip install Django-webpush » (no mistake), I executed « python manage.py migrate » (in line with instructions on host as well, no mistake at this point, migration is done successfully).

I have the Error when I try to reload the application on host.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you pip install it in the venv that your web app is running in?

Comment: I have done it with pip install -r  requirements.txt with all other packages. I was inside of my project dirr doing that. So I suppose, that yes. I read in one tutorial, that webpush may require implementation of ngrok and building secure tunnel. I suppose this is necessary when you use your local server.  While my app is in pythonanywhere cloud.

Comment: I solved it doing pip install django-webpush in the consol opened in my virtual environment. Not just regular bash from the dashboard. It works properly, application is up and running. Thank you!

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks